# How to add the server license for reavenDB with docker composer

Tags: docker-compose, ravendb

Some how it's not clear how to add the server license for ravenDB in a docker compose file.

**Docker compose**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  raven1:
    container_name: raven1
    image: ravendb/ravendb
    ports:
      - 8091:8080
      - 38888:38888
    environment:
      - RAVEN_Setup_Mode=None
      - RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
      - RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PrivateNetwork
      - RAVEN_License_Path=/Users/********/projects/RavenDB/license.json
    volumes:
      - /Users/********/projects/RavenDB/Data:/opt/RavenDB/Server/RavenData
```

**license.json**

```
{
    "Id": "da9446f7-ad2e-4267-ae62-47ff2f34bc86",
    "Name": "Swisscom",
    "Keys": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

The license is not added.
**What is the correct way to add this server license.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the variable RAVEN_License_Path shows the license path inside the docker. So it should be

```
RAVEN_License_Path=/opt/RavenDB/Server/RavenLicense/license.json
```

and add this volume

```
- /Users/********/projects/RavenLicense:/opt/RavenDB/Server/RavenLicense
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `RAVEN_License_Path` looks like it is pointing to a path on your host machine, and therefore it can't be found from within the container.

Ie it's just an environment variable containing an arbitrary path and the server running within the container will try to resolve this path. But of course it can't because it's a path from an entirely unrelated file system.

So you have two possibilities

1. You create a new image based on `ravendb/ravendb` where you add your licensefile
2. You put your licensefile into a folder that is mounted into the container (similar to your data volume) IMO this is the preferred solution.

In both cases, you need to change your `RAVEN_Licence_Path` to be a valid path within the running container.

Comment: I got the point, thx. That helped.